# Magento 2 - Remove last name from registration form

Tags: magento2, customer, register

How to remove the last name field in registration form?

Comment: did you get the solution to remove the validations for last name?

Answer (score 3):

You have to copy file from

```
projectroot\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

And paste to in you theme.

You can find class **field-name-lastname** in code. delete complete this div for last name.

You have to run below query in your database for set lastname as optional for customer.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and `entity_type_id` = 1
```

Run Command : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: It is not a complete solution. It just hide the field from display. But the form validation is not passed as last name is a required form. How to remove the validation also?

Comment: You can see my updated answer for set last name as optional.

Comment: @S H Patel, it is not working.

Comment: What error come now ?

Comment: It still said that last name is required when submitting the register form.

Comment: Please check in table, what values of is_required for lastname.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43186/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-zzpaul).

Comment: @SHPatel I have fallowed above 2 steps, but still getting the validation error as **lastname is a required field**. Could you help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run SQL query in your database to set last name as optional or remove:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 1
```

Go to below file where you can find class field-name-lastname in code. delete complete this div for last name.

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

Note : We recommended to override the core files

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the context of class `Setup/InstallData` and method `install()` while implementing `\Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface` you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
 */
public function install(
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    $customerSetup = $this->_customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup $customerSetup */

    // Make lastname optional
    $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
      \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
      'lastname',
      'is_required',
      false
    );
}
```

Then you can hide the `lastname` field with **CSS** like this:

```
fieldset.fieldset.create.info .field-name-lastname
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why do you recommend to hide a field with css instead of using other proper methods?

Comment: Sometimes a client is not willing to pay for the extra work to make a more proper solution, a CSS fix is done in a minute or two while a more proper solution could take hours depending on what theme hierarchy and modules you have on a setup.